# Bootstrap form onSubmit and onClick is not firing the expected function. Button works when outside form component

Tags: reactjs, axios, reactstrap

I have created a book search react application that uses the openLibrary API to search for books. I have a form group that should submit a GET request either on a form submit or a button click.

My issue is that neither the button nor the form retrieves data when I submit it.

I tried moving the `Button` component outside of the `Form` component, and it worked as expected; however, it doesn't work when I move it back into the `Form` component

I tried binding the functions, but when I click the button or hit the enter key to submit my API request, it doesn't work for some reason

can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong, please?

#### Here is my code

##### App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from "reactstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.scss";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.searchBooks = this.searchBooks.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      booksData: [],
      searchQuery: "",
    };
  }

  searchBooks = () => {
    axios
      .get(`http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=${this.state.searchQuery}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data.docs;

        this.setState({
          booksData: data,
          searchQuery: "",
        });
      });
  };

  onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    let searchQ = event.target.value;
    searchQ = searchQ.replace(/\s+/g, "+").toLowerCase();

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      searchQuery: searchQ,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form onSubmit={() => this.searchBooks}>
          <FormGroup className="form-group container">
            <Label for="search-field" id="search-label">
              Search:{" "}
            </Label>
            <Input
              id="search-field"
              name="search books"
              placeholder="Book Title"
              type="input"
              onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
            ></Input>
            <Button
            color="primary"
            size="md"
            className="search-btn"
            type="submit"
            onClick={() => this.searchBooks}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
        <Table className="books-table container">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Book Title</th>
              <th>Book Author</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.booksData.map((book) => (
              <tr key={book.key}>
                <td>{book.title}</td>
                <td>{book.author_name}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

##### App.scss

```css
.page-title{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.books-table{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.form-group{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;

  .search-btn{
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  #search-field{
    width: 40%;
  }

  #search-label{
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

#### UPDATE:

I changed the `onClick` and the `onSubmit` functions to be the following, and it doesn't work either:

```js
<Form onSubmit={this.searchBooks}>
 <FormGroup className="form-group container">
  <Label for="search-field" id="search-label">
   Search:{" "}
  </Label>
  <Input
   id="search-field"
   name="search books"
   placeholder="Book Title"
   type="input"
   onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
   ></Input>
   <Button
    color="primary"
    size="md"
    className="search-btn"
    type="submit"
    onClick={this.searchBooks}
    >
    Search
    </Button>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the `this.searchBooks()` function inside the arrow function. But you didn't. You pass as a reference only therefore nothing executed.
You can either do `onSubmit={this.searchBooks}` or `onSubmit={()=> this.searchBooks()}`. If your searchBooks function take any parameter, the second approach is the way to go

Comment: I changed both the onClick and onSubmit functions to your suggestions, and it doesn't work either. I added the change in the initial question

Answer (score 0):

You use arrow function so you should execute or pass as a reference

```
onSubmit={()=> this.searchBooks()}
```

or

```
onSubmit={this.searchBooks}
```

Comment: I changed both the onClick and onSubmit functions to your suggestions, and it doesn't work either. I added the change in the initial question